Missing generation from graphql-codegen for Upload
The following is the nestjs and react native related code. I expect it will generate useGetNumbersQuery, but it only generate the QueryDocument.
nestjs
"graphql-upload": "^15.0.0",
num.resolver.ts
@Query(() => [Int], { name: 'getNumbers' })
async getNumbers(
@Args('getNumbersInput') getNumbersInput: GetNumbersInput
) {
//
}

GetNumbersInput.ts
import { Field, InputType, Int } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import * as GraphQLUpload from 'graphql-upload/GraphQLUpload.js';
import * as Upload from 'graphql-upload/Upload.js';
import { IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

@InputType()
export class GetNumbersInput {
  @Field(() => GraphQLUpload)
  file: Upload;
}

react native
"@graphql-codegen/cli": "^5.0.2",
"@graphql-codegen/introspection": "^4.0.3",
"@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^4.0.9",
"@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^4.2.3",
"@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^4.3.0",
num.gql
query Query($getNumbersInput: GetNumbersInput!) {
  getNumbers(getNumbersInput: $getNumbersInput)
}

codegen.yml
overwrite: true
schema: ${API_URL}
documents: "**/*.{gql,graphql}"
generates:
  ./generated/schema.ts:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-react-apollo"
    config:
      scalars:
        Upload: "File"

generated/schema.ts
export type GetNumbersInput = {
  file: Scalars['Upload']['input'];
};

export const QueryDocument = gql`
    query Query($getNumbersInput: GetNumbersInput!) {
  getNumbers(getNumbersInput: $getNumbersInput)
}
    `;

